# How can I have the aggregated values based with custom fields using mongoDB/mongoose aggregation pipeline?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am developing a shopping cart and my current requirement is to display a dashboard to shop owners. Since there may be a duplication in Products' name, I have grouped ordered products on product ID and performed sum to have total number of orders. Now I also need readable name but doing so raises an error.

The query

```
ShoppingCart
    .aggregate({ $match: { "orderedProducts.registrationDetails.createdByID": LOGGED_IN_ADMIS_ID } })
    .project("orderedProducts.productID orderedProducts.title  orderedProducts.qty -_id")
    .unwind("orderedProducts")
    .group({ _id: "$orderedProducts.productID", counts: { $sum: "$orderedProducts.qty" }, title: "$orderedProducts.title" })
    .exec((err, docs) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(503).send(err);
        }
        res.send(docs);
    });
```

Error message :

> {"name":"MongoError","message":"The field 'title' must be an
>   accumulator object","ok":0,"errmsg":"The field 'title' must be an
>   accumulator object","code":40234,"codeName":"Location40234"}

this is the part which is the cause of error *title: "$orderedProducts.title"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue may be in your `group` operator. Specifically, you're doing `title: "$orderedProducts.title"`, which may be causing issues with the grouping. MongoDB probably doesn't understand how to handle this case as there is no way to prioritize which title from which document to use. This is why some form of accumulator is expected, e.g. the `$sum` you're using on the `qty` field.

Instead, try omitting the `title` portion of the grouping and instead using a compound `_id`:

```
ShoppingCart
    .aggregate({ $match: { "orderedProducts.registrationDetails.createdByID": LOGGED_IN_ADMIS_ID } })
    .project("orderedProducts.productID orderedProducts.title  orderedProducts.qty -_id")
    .unwind("orderedProducts")
    .group({ _id: { productId: "$orderedProducts.productID", title: "$orderedProducts.title" }, counts: { $sum: "$orderedProducts.qty" } })
    .exec((err, docs) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(503).send(err);
        }
        res.send(docs);
    });
```

The caveat to this solution is that it assumes that for each `productID` there is only the one title. It will group by both `productID` and `title`, so any differing titles for the same `productID` will cause this solution to fail. If this is an issue for you and you want to grab all product titles for the given `productID` instead, you can do the following:

```
ShoppingCart
    .aggregate({ $match: { "orderedProducts.registrationDetails.createdByID": LOGGED_IN_ADMIS_ID } })
    .project("orderedProducts.productID orderedProducts.title  orderedProducts.qty -_id")
    .unwind("orderedProducts")
    .group({ _id: "$orderedProducts.productID", counts: { $sum: "$orderedProducts.qty" }, titles: { $addToSet: "$orderedProducts.title" } })
    .exec((err, docs) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(503).send(err);
        }
        res.send(docs);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

either use $last or $first in the group pipeline

```
.group({ 
     _id: "$orderedProducts.productID", 
     counts: { $sum: "$orderedProducts.qty" }, 
     title: { $first:"$orderedProducts.title"} 
})
```

or,

```
.group({ 
     _id: "$orderedProducts.productID", 
     counts: { $sum: "$orderedProducts.qty" }, 
     title: { $last:"$orderedProducts.title"} 
})
```

Since you're grouping the products, the title should remain against similar product_id. so u can select the first one or the last one to be attached with the final grouped object

Comment: Dear @imixtron thank you for your suggestion. The problem is, name of the product is not unique in my case. There is a probability that the user may create 2 or more different products with exactly same name, this is why I was grouping the products in product ID instead of name.

Comment: my query does the same the grouping is based on **_id**. so all the grouped documents will have the same one. hence you can either select one from the start or from the end.